# tex4ht: epstopdf not firing at all

Tags: tex4ht, epstopdf

I am using the following calls for epstopdf in the Preamble, and was able to successfully convert .eps files to .svg in the /converted_graphics folder for another tex4ht project that had no problems.

```
\Configure{graphics*}
   {eps}
   {\openin15=\csname Gin@base\endcsname\PictExt\relax%
   \ifeof15%
   \Needs{"epstopdf \csname Gin@base\endcsname.eps && pdf2svg \csname Gin@base\endcsname.pdf \csname Gin@base\endcsname.svg"}
   \fi%
   \closein15%
   {\Configure{Needs}{File: \csname Gin@base\endcsname\PictExt}\Needs{}}%
   \Picture[\csname a:GraphicsAlt\endcsname]{{\csname Gin@base\endcsname\PictExt} \csname a:Gin-dim\endcsname
}}
```

The current problem is that although I am using .eps filename extensions in all the \includegraphics commands, the epstopdf program is not firing.  This is interesting since the same Preamble commands used in .cfg for another project worked with no issues.   Question is, why is epstopdf not firing at all?

Comment: I think we need a `mwe` with a minimal TeX file and some of the EPS files

Comment: For epstopdf, isn't that bundled into MiKTeK 2.9, and does not need path settings in DOS (Windows cmd)?  As long as I have the correct "Needs epstopdf..." in the preamble (.cfg) epstopdf should be initialized and start.   Recall, using the same cmd syntax, everything ran before without a glitch.

Comment: @JoleT the configuration tests for existence of the converted SVG file, so it doesn't execute `epstopdf` if the target SVG already exists

Comment: This was resolved, so thanks for the help.  works like a charm, so no problems with MiKTeX 2.9, tex4ht, or DOS paths, and cmd escapes, etc.